# Communicating with a chrome extension from an external url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following javascript code for a chrome extension which works well from the url of the extension, I mean something like:

chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/main.html

**This is the code**

```
var port = null;

$(function(){
    $('.button_generate').click(function(){
        $('.progressbar').removeClass('hidden');
        connect();
        port.postMessage({"comment": "Overland Park"});
    });
    $('.button_save_greeting').click(function(){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik', {greeting: "hello"}, {}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
function connect() {
    var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}
function onNativeMessage(message) {
    $('.greeting').val(message['greeting']);
    port.disconnect();
    $('.greeting').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.progressbar').addClass('hidden');
}
function onDisconnected() {
    port = null;
}
```

My question is if I can send messages to this chrome extension from an external url, I mean something like:

http://localhost/myproject/test.html

On the manifest of the plugin I have:

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost/*"]
}
```

but the communication doesn't go thru.

My other question is how do I configure the chrome extension to answer the messages it receives from **test.html**?

Comment: Use [onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).